# Problem with grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

How do i get rid of the grease pencil marks in blender? I put a couple marks on my mesh by mistake and i want to get rid of em all. I already tried using erase and it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add more information about the eraser issue? Do you see the red circle around the cursor when you run the command? Do you have multiple Grease Pencil layers?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Grease Pencil layers controller the **Properties panel** of the 3D Viewport

[image]

Press the button under the cursor in the picture to remove the acrive layer and, consequently, **all** the strokes contained in it.